# Magento - How to set Super Product sort order on import

Tags: magento

I am importing simple and configurable products using the magento Import.  When associated products (super products) are imported the order is set to what appears to be alphabetical order based on the attribute name.  The order of these can be changed in admin by dragging the attributes.  It appears the order is kept in the catalog_product_super_attribute table in the ‘position’ column.  But, so far I’ve found no way to import this order.

Is there are parameter I can add to the CSV file to import this value.